# How "unhide" service created with sc

Tags: windows, service

I'd like to start additional instance of existing .net windows service on old Windows 2003 R2 SE. I copied files to new directory and I used sc command to create it:

```
sc create "MyServiceSecondary" binPath= "C:\Program Files\MyServiceSecondary\MyService.exe" DisplayName= "Secondary instance of my service" start= auto start= auto obj= ".\LocalSystem"
```

and then started it:

```
sc start "MyServiceSecondary"
```

The service started, task manager lists it, but the Windows Service Manager doesn't show it. How "unhide" it?

Comment: Does it show in Windows Service Manager after you reboot?

Comment: No, after reboot Windows Serwice Manager shows only first instance.